# How does JavaScript "writable" property descriptor work?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, ecmascript-5

Why does the JavaScript "writable" property descriptor not forbid any property changes?

For example:

```
var TheDarkKnight = Object.create(Superhero, {
    "name": {
        value:"Batman",
        writable:"false"
    }
});

TheDarkKnight.name; //"Batman";

TheDarkKnight.name = "Superman";
TheDarkKnight.name; //"Superman";
```

I thought `TheDarkKnight.name` should still return `"Batman"` after I tried to change it to another value because I set the "writable" property descriptor to `false`.

So how to use it in the right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `false`, not `"false"`. In other words, it should be a boolean.

If you don't pass a boolean, then whatever value you give will be coerced to a boolean, and `Boolean("false") === true; // true`, so you were effectively passing `writable:true`.

```
var TheDarkKnight = Object.create(Superhero, {
    "name": {
        value:"Batman",
        writable:false // boolean false (or any falsey value)
    }
});

TheDarkKnight.name; //"Batman";

TheDarkKnight.name = "Superman";
TheDarkKnight.name; //"Batman";
```

Also, note that `writable:false` is the default value, so if you just remove that setting from the descriptor, the property will not be writable.