# Object.defineProperty or .prototype?

Tags: javascript, string, object, prototype, defineproperty

I've seen two different techniques of implementing non-native features in javascript,
First is:

```
if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
    Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'startsWith', {
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: false,
        writable: false,
        value: function(searchString, position) {
            position = position || 0;
            return this.lastIndexOf(searchString, position) === position;
        }
    });
}
```

and Second is:

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function(searchString, position) {
    position = position || 0;
    return this.lastIndexOf(searchString, position) === position;
}
```

I know that the second one is used to attach any method to the prototype chain of a particular standard built-in objects, but first technique is new to me.
Can anybody explain what is the difference between them, why one is used and why one not and what are their significances.

Comment: [did you look up `Object.defineProperty` to attempt to understand how it works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)?

Comment: `enumerable`, `configurable`, and `writable` all default to `false` and thus are not necessary. In any case, the advantage of this is that, uhh, properties so defined are not enumerable, configurable, or writable, all of which you probably want.

Comment: Yes, but found the official documentation on `developer.mozilla.org` slightly confusing. If we can add a property to prototype of particular standard built-in objects then what does `defineProperty` actually do, that was confusing part.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In two cases you are adding a new property 'startsWith' in `String.prototype`.

First differs from the second in this cases:

You can configure the property to be `enumerable`, `writable` and `configurable`.

**[Writable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892375/how-does-javascript-writable-property-descriptor-work)** - `true` means that you can change its value by assigning any value. If false - you can't change the value

```js
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'startsWith', {
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: false,
        writable: false, // Set to False
        value: function(searchString, position) {
            position = position || 0;
            return this.lastIndexOf(searchString, position) === position;
        }
    });

var test = new String('Test');

test.startsWith = 'New Value';
console.log(test.startsWith); // It still have the previous value in non strict mode
```

**[Enumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893718/what-does-enumerable-mean)** - `true` means that it will be seen in the `for in` loop.

```js
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'startsWith', {
        enumerable: true, // Set to True
        configurable: false,
        writable: false, 
        value: function(searchString, position) {
            position = position || 0;
            return this.lastIndexOf(searchString, position) === position;
        }
    });

var test = new String('Test');

for(var key in test){
   console.log(key)  ;
}
```

[**Configurable**](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-objects-and-properties/) - `true` if and only if the type of this property descriptor may be changed and if the property may be deleted from the corresponding object.

```js
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'startsWith', {
            enumerable: false,
            configurable: false, // Set to False
            writable: false, 
            value: function(searchString, position) {
                position = position || 0;
                return this.lastIndexOf(searchString, position) === position;
            }
        });

    
    delete String.prototype.startsWith; // It will not delete the property
    console.log(String.prototype.startsWith);
```

And one advice to you, **don't change the prototypes of build in types**.

Comment: Okk, that means by using`defineProperty`, we can set the behavior of required property to what we want to be, is that right?

Comment: Yes you are right. If you will define a property and miss the writable, enumerable and configurable their values will be `false` by default

Comment: Thanks for your demonstration with code, it is really a **big** help in understanding the scenario.. Thanks again..