# typescript class decorator to extends method

Tags: angularjs, typescript, overriding, aop, decorator

I searched a lot for decorator explantion with typescript but I don't find complete documentation that I can apply on my purpose.

I found two possible solution : AOP and Decorator but I understand that aop is "not yet ready".

The idea is -- I have some security library to implements and I need to call some method "enterAction" and "leaveAction" when current page change.

I have angular/ionic livecycle events for page change (load/leave).
And I'd like to "override" them in one place because I don't want to modify each page component. (When I will add a new one, I will forget to implement it).

So The idea was to add a decorator on each page class. In this decorator add call to my secure library (enter/leaveAction) when event (load/leave) are called.

Actually I can create decorator on class. But I don't know how to overide method call.

Currently I defined my class decorator liek that :

```
@security
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>Hello Angular!</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    private toto= "demo";
    constructor() {
        console.log("construct!");
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('onInit');
        this.method1();
    }
    method1() {
        console.log('method 1 : '+ this.toto);
    }
}


function security<TFunction extends Function>(target: TFunction): TFunction     {
    var method1 = target.prototype.method1;
    Object.defineProperty(target.prototype, 'method1', {
        value: function() {
            console.log('enterAction here');
            // How to call real method1() here ?
            // Call of method1() will fail since it don't know AppCompnent.toto here
            return '';
        }
    });
    return target;
}
```

Regards,

EDIT

Finaly, I found an other way without using decorator to solve my problem.

Answer (score 4):

You're very close, you just need to use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
function security<TFunction extends Function>(target: TFunction): TFunction     {
    var method1 = target.prototype.method1;
    Object.defineProperty(target.prototype, 'method1', {
        value: function() {
            console.log('enterAction here');
            return method1.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    });
    return target;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it tell

`error    t ionViewWillEnter error: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`

Comment: That's a runtime error, it means that the class that was passed to the decorator did not have `method1`.  When I ran it, it worked, so I guess you are running code that is different than what you posted?

Comment: Finaly, I found an other way to subscribe to the method. Method1 is subscribable. And in my AppComponent (with ionic) I use `this.nav._app.method1.subscribe(...` But thanks for your help.
I will check more in depth decoraters later.

Comment: In this example, why do you have to use `Object.defineProperty` instead of just saying `target.prototype.method1 = ...`?

Comment: @Cam The OP used `Object.defineProperty` so I used it as well, as for the differences, there are answers for this specific questions, i.e.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961414/object-defineproperty-or-prototype